# Заменить стрелочную функцию

Tags: javascript, функции

Помогите пожалуйста заменить стрелочные функции в следующем коде:

```
let allService = [{Name: "Услуга №1", Code: "1", Kind: "Услуга №1"}, {Name: "Услуга №2", Code: "2", Kind: "Услуга №2"}, {Name: "Услуга №6", Code: "6", Kind: "Услуга №6"}, {Name: "Услуга №3", Code: "3", Kind: "Услуга №3"}];
let myService = [{Service: '2'}, {Service: '6'}, {Service: '1'}];

let notMyService = allService.filter(service => myService.every(item => item.Service !== service.Code));

console.log(notMyService);
```

Comment: Заменить на что? "На пиво, тормоз!" - "Каникулы строгого режима"

Comment: На обычную формата "function(arg) { // Code }"... IE не принимает такие функции к сожалению

Comment: Ну посмотрите в чём отличия и измените... слишком лениво?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let notMyService = allService.filter(function(service) {
  return myService.every(function(item) { 
    return item.Service !== service.Code; 
  });
});
```